# Mysql - group by week but start counting from 1

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have this query:

```sql
select 
week(sr.transactionDate) AS week_number,
sum(sr.digitalEarnings)
from
sales_report as sr
where `sr`.`transactionDate` BETWEEN '2022-05-01' AND '2022-12-31'
group by week_number
order by week_number;
```

Which returns data like so:

[image]

I know this is the "week in the year" number but I'm actually trying to get the data divided into weeks starting from 1. i.e Week 1 in this period, week 2 in this period etc.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: how about using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (group by week_number
order by week_number)` ??

Comment: @catzilla Thanks for the comment, how would the query look with that? I'm not overly familiar with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER`

Comment: Subtract week number of the starting date from the week number?

Comment: @SalmanA Lol, so simple! Yes, that works. It's actually twice as fast as using ROW_NUMBER too.

Comment: @webnoob posted as answer. If window functions are available it is very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate week number directly from the transaction date.  Assuming you have left the default_week_format system variable unchanged, you are doing weeks starting with Sunday; adjust your range start date to find the Sunday on or before, and count the weeks from that to the transaction date, adding one to start with week 1, not week 0:

```
floor(datediff(sr.transactionDate,'2022-05-01' - interval dayofweek('2022-05-01')-1 day) / 7) + 1
```

I strongly suggest not using week() at all; its behavior across years or near the beginning or end of years is usually not friendly for reporting purposes.  Especially subtracting or comparing two week values can be problematic.

Comment: oops, fixed day of week

Answer (score 0):

how about using `ROW_NUMBER()` although this is only available in v8 and above:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number

```
SELECT 
    week(sr.transactionDate) AS week_number,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (GROUP BY week_number ORDER BY week_number) AS week_n,
    sum(sr.digitalEarnings)
 FROM
     sales_report as sr
 WHERE `sr`.`transactionDate` BETWEEN '2022-05-01' AND '2022-12-31'
 GROUP BY week_number
 ORDER BY week_number;
```

Comment: I'm on MySQL 8.0.28 and getting an error with this: > Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY week_number ORDER BY week_number) AS week_n,     sum(sr.digitalEarnings' at line 3.

Any thoughts?

I tried not using the alias inside the over() and using the week(sr.transactionDate) but that didn't help.

Comment: try using `ROW_NUMBER() over sr as week_n `

Comment: `window name 'sr' is not defined` when doing that. Same if I use sales_report directly.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS week_n` does work and produces a row number per row, but obviously doesn't adhere to the grouping. So ROW_NUMBER() is compatible at least :)

Comment: that's good to hear, I guess its one problem less now. keep us posted :)

Comment: Oh wait, just the row number is fine .... As it's grouped already. `ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS week_n,` is correct. Don't need to group again inside over()

Comment: Inside OVER it's actually PARTITION BY, not GROUP BY. You don't need it though, you do need `OVER (ORDER BY week(sr.transactionDate))`. If you omit ORDER BY then there is no guarantee which order the row numbers are assigned.

Comment: @SalmanA I've actually gone with your minus week number approach. It was so simple I didn't think about it... 
Would you like to add an answer so I can accept?

Comment: this doesn't work well if there are weeks with no earnings; presumably they would want week number to have gaps in that case

Comment: Ah yes, good point. That's correct.

Comment: re comment "obviously doesn't adhere to the grouping", row_number and other window functions are applied to rows post-grouping.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I saw that after examining closely. Good to know.